# Regular Expression in python, a particular case

Tags: python, regex

I newbie in python and I'm trying to extract a value from string but it doesn't work.
my string is something like:

```
<a href=​"/​profile/​view?id=34232962&goback=%2Enmp_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1&trk=spm_pic" title=​"View your profile">​
```

My attempt is:

```
m = re.search('^.*\b(view|your|profile)\b.*$', newp, re.IGNORECASE)
print m.group(0)
```

The desired output:

```
/​profile/​view?id=34232962&goback=%2Enmp_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1 trk=spm_pic
```

Comment: what is your input?href's value or anchor tag

Comment: it is webpage that I downloaded first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah? You want to crawl LinkedIn private pages? ;)

Something like that should work:

```
m = re.search('href="(/profile/[^"]+)"', newp, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But, as usual, **don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**.

Comment: Since the webpage has multiple href tags, your solution dose not work

Comment: what should I use instead ?

Comment: @Afshin I modified my regex to only match profile urls. LinkedIn provides a REST API: http://developer.linkedin.com/rest It provides most the information you may want for a user profile.

Comment: thank you! first for regex yes It works, and second for your advice

Answer (score 3):

Regex is horrible for parsing HTML as you have found out.  Use a tool built for the job.  In the case of python, use BeautifulSoup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
profile_a = soup.find(title="View your profile")
link = profile_a['href']
print link
>> /​profile/​view?id=34232962&goback=%2Enmp_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1 trk=spm_pic
```

Comment: Good solution, I will check it and will answer soon, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that `*` is *greedy*, i.e. it will try to match maximum number of chars. So in your example (if matching href only):

```
'^.*\b(view|your|profile)\b.*$'

.../​profile/​view?id=34232962&goback=%2Enmp_*1_*1_*...
^---------^ matched by '.*'
           ^ \b
            ^--^ matched by 'view'
                ^ \b
                 ^------... - matched by .*
```

If matching full string:

```
... title=​"View your profile">
^------------------^ - .*
                    ^ \b
                     ^-----^ - 'profile'
                            ^ \b
                             ^ - .*
```

Another note: `^.*<regex>.*$` is effectively the same as just `<regex>`

What you probably want is: `href="([^"]*)"` - this will match whatever is in `href="..."`